# Проблемма с мышью в pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, archlinux, manjaro

Есть код, который обрабатывает событие с нажимом левой кнопки мыши:

```py
        elif i.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if i.button == 1:
                x = i.pos[0]
                y = H
                while y > 0:
                    sc.fill(WHITE)
                    pygame.draw.circle(sc, RED, (x, y), 20)
                    y -= 2
                    pygame.display.update()
```

Он создёт объект с задержкой, это если использовать usb мышь, если тачпад, то отклик првильный. Использую Linux Manjaro 18.1.3, kde

Comment: мне кажется это проблема не с кодом, а с вашим девайсом

Comment: alex9127, да так и есть, спустя некоторое время после написание этого вопроса я подключил другую мышь, и всё было нормально.